# Remove value from dictionary element in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries, namely

```
bandits = [{'health': 15, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 10, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 12, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}]
hero = [{'name': "Arthur", 'health': 50, 'damage': 5, 'id': 0}]
```

What I would like to do, is simulate a `hero` strike on each member of the `bandits` list, which consist in substracting the `damage` value of `hero` to the `health` value of each `bandits` entry. As an illustration, with the values given above, after the `hero` has dealt its blow, the `bandits` list should read

```
bandits = [{'health': 10, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 5, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 7, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}]
```

I have tried several things, amongst which

```
for i, v in enumerate(bandits):
    bandits[i] = {k: (bandits[i][k] - hero[0].get('damage')) for k in bandits[i] if k=='health'}
```

which yields

```
bandits = [{'health': 10}, {'health': 5}, {'health': 7}]
```

i.e. the results for the health are good, but all other `key:val` pairs in the dictionaries contained in the `bandits` list are deleted. How can I correct my code?

Comment: Don't replace the entire dictionary, only update the value for a single key.

Comment: Don't write everything in a single line, you are confusing yourself. Use the pattern: (1) get current value from dictionary (2) calculate new value from current value (3) insert new value in dictionary. This should be at least 3 statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depended on the goals/use case you can iterate the collection and update the value in-place (variable names are used from the *"I have tried several things"* code):

```py
bandit = [{'health': 15, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 10, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}, {'health': 12, 'damage': 2, 'id': 0}]
knight_data = [{'name': "Arthur", 'health': 50, 'damage': 5, 'id': 0}]

for b in bandit:
    for k in knight_data:
        b['health'] -= k['damage']
```

Or:

```py
for b in bandit:
    b['health'] -= knight_data[0]['damage']
```

Comment: @KellyBundy 1) thank you, updated, 2) check out _"I have tried several things, amongst which"_ OP code in. There is no `hero` used.

Comment: Ah, that line is too long to fit on my screen :-)

Comment: Still, I'd choose the name stated first and more often (and is shorter).

Answer (score 0):

Don't create new dictionaries, just subtract from the values in the existing dictionaries.

```
for bandit in bandits:
    bandit['health'] -= hero[0]['damage']
```

Comment: your code is similar to the previous answer, hence it does the trick. Thank you.